# Image not displaying in the container using Future Function but is display when i use image Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, hybrid-mobile-app

The code is suppose to display a picture in the container but its not displaying anything! other than the text. I used Image.asser() and that works and displays an image in the container but when i use SelectedImage and store a picture in it using Future Function from gallery or camera that doesn't work and won't display any picture in the Container
when i provide SelectedImage directly i-e **child: SelectedImage** i get this error
**The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:project1_test/theme/Textstyle.dart';
import 'package:project1_test/theme/colors.dart';

class ImageSelectionfunction extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageSelectionfunction({super.key});

  @override
  State<ImageSelectionfunction> createState() => _ImageSelectionfunctionState();
}

class _ImageSelectionfunctionState extends State<ImageSelectionfunction> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    File? SelectedImage;
    Future<void> pickImage() async {
      final picker = ImagePicker();
      final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (pickedImage != null) {
        setState(() {
          SelectedImage = File(pickedImage.path);
        });
      }
    }

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
         //The below container is suppose to display the picture
          child: Container( 
            width: 220,
            height: 190,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey,
                offset: Offset(0, 4),
                blurRadius: 5,
                spreadRadius: 5,
              )
            ]),
            child: SelectedImage != null
                ? Image.file(File(SelectedImage!.path))
                : const Text('Your Image here'),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 35,
        ),

        ////////////////////////////
        //Image Selection Buttons
        //////////////////////////
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 180,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: purpleColor,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                    child: Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.image,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 17,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text(
                      'Pick From Gallery',
                      style: txtStyle,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      pickImage();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 160,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: purpleColor,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                    child: Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.camera,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 17,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text(
                      'Take a Picture',
                      style: txtStyle,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        ////////////////////////
        //Buttons Area Ends Here
        ////////////////////////

        ///////////////////////
        //Prediction Button
        ///////////////////////
        SizedBox(
          height: 12,
        ),
        Container(
          width: 180,
          height: 60,
          color: purpleColor,
          child: Row(children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              child: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.magnifyingGlass,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 18,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 12,
            ),
            Text(
              'Start Prediction',
              style: txtStylemain,
            ),
          ]),
        )
        //////////////////////////////
        //Prediction Button Ends Here
        ////////////////////////////
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you put `SelectedImage` declaration inside the build method. When you use `setState`, the build method will be recalled and `SelectedImage` will be redeclared with the initial value `null`.

To fix it, move your `SelectedImage` variable outside the build method (put it in the widget state).

```dart
class _ImageSelectionfunctionState extends State<ImageSelectionfunction> {
  File? SelectedImage;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Image.file(File(SelectedImage!.path))
```

I believe this should be changed to this since you are already assigning `File` type to `SelectedImage` variable

```
Image.file(SelectedImage)
```

Comment: Image.file(SelectedImage!) it still doesn't display any picture i need to add ! else  The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'